# how to set setInterval in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

i am trying to call a function in reactjs using `setInterval` like this:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

trigger(){
   this.clock = this.setState({clock:Date.now()-this.props.date});
}
setInterval(this.trigger,1000);
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    clock:0
    };
    this.trigger = this.trigger.bind(this);
}

render(){
    this.state.clock=Math.round(this.state.clock/1000);
    return(
        <div>
            <p>You are here since</p>
            <span>{this.state.clock}</span>
            <p>Seconds.</p>
            <button onClick={this.trigger}>Click me</button>
       </div>
   );
}
}

export default Timer;
```

Which returns this error instead:

```
Syntax error: F:/reactjs1/project-6/timer/src/Timer.js: Unexpected token (8:22)
Syntax error: F:/reactjs1/project-6/timer/src/Timer.js: Unexpected token (8:22)

6 |     this.clock = this.setState({clock:Date.now()-this.props.date});
7 |   }
>   8 |   setInterval(trigger,1000);
                        ^
```

Comment: try `setInterval(this.trigger,1000);` and put in componentDidMount lifecycle.

Comment: same error is showing now its showing on this

Comment: Please post the code of the entire component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
trigger() {
    let newTime = Date.now() - this.props.date;
    setInterval(() => { 
        this.setState({
            clock: newTime;
        })
    }, 1000);
}
```

You can execute this function in a variety of ways, with the best option likely being within the component or container's componentDidMount(). This will then run every second, updating the value of this.clock each time.